# What is the rationale behind using a third party uninstaller, when uninstalling applications on a Windows PC?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

Whenever I uninstall an application or program from my Windows 7 PC, I always go to the Control Panel and use the inbuilt utility within Windows to accomplish this, and then reboot the PC.

Is there therefore a rationale to use a freeware third party uninstaller instead eg [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/), to carry out the same task and may it actually be doing more harm than good (if one is not careful) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not see how it would be of benefit, everything in add/ remove programs or the appwiz.cpl is in the registry at **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall** as a subkey.

[image]

MSI installers write their GUID in the format **{AFF7153F-C4AA-4C48-AEE9-8611D276CE86}**

This is not really a problem, as much as a difficulty in reading the keys. There are couple ways to read through these. One, there is a Value Name DisplayName that will have the more friendly value of (in this example) Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell for Active Directory (x64).

Another approach, is Windows writes a “compressed and hashed” version of the GUID to another part of the Registry.

To Hash the value, take the GUID {AFF7153F-C4AA-4C48-AEE9-8611D276CE86} and reverse each set of hex values.
AFF7153F becomes F3517FFA, C4AA becomes AA4C and on down the GUID until you have the following:
**{F3517FFA-C4AA-84C4-9EEA-68EC672D1168}**

Now, drop the {, -, and } to get **F3517FFAC4AA84C49EEA68EC672D1168**
You now have the compressed and hashed GUID that you can compare to another key.

You should now be able to find this new GUID at the following location in the Registry:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products**

[image]

Essentially, all uninstalling from the appwiz.cpl or Add/remove programs does is call the uninstall string HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, you can easily copy this command in the command prompt and achieve the same results.

As for orphaned files that a third party uninstaller claims to remove, I would not accept the risk as low enough for the little gains. Usually what is left behind is of no consequence, a registry key with license information or a key, or a *C:\Program Files\ApplicationName* folder that I can easily delete myself. I have seen applications try to wipe shared dll files though, and I would 10 times as worried about something like Reno catching a reference to a shared dll and cleaning it for me, breaking another install.

Comment: good detailed explanation :)

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn Thanks, these are actually from notes I made myself a while back when working on a C# tool to enumerate remote computers installed applications.

Comment: @AthomSfere Appreciate the technicality of your answer, to reinforce what Lorenzo was saying (even if I don't fully understand it IMHO). It will be interesting to see if anyone comes on here in defence of third party uninstallers (and flips the coin - so to speak).

Comment: @AthomSfere I forgot to add thankyou for your reference with regards to orphaned files.

Answer (score 6):

Third party unistallers follow the same philosophy as registry cleaners - do not use them.

They can easily be described in two words: Snake Oil.

In real IT environments they are not used for the simple reason they are just that - snake oil - and are prone to cause more trouble than to fix things.

Comment: Just to clarify you always use the inbuilt utility, but also isn't it possible that debris for example orphaned or obselete files sometimes get left behind ?

Comment: it is possible. but aamof, we can never predict what the software will do in order to attempt an uninstall.

Comment: Obviously it is better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: While I agree these programs are snake oil, one has to understand, they don't magically do anything different then uninstaller for the program itself does, they can't because, they don't know what files belong to what program.

Comment: @Simon - There is nothing that Revo does that running the default uninstaller can't do.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes and also if they are indeed similar to registry cleaners, I certainly wouldn't want to mess with the registry (may lead to unforeseen problems).

Comment: I don't quite agree.  Registry cleaners are 100% useless; 3rd party uninstall tools are only 99.9% useless.  The difference is that the latter can be useful when the first party uninstall catastrophically fails for some reason and either aborts without uninstalling or fails messily breaking the system in the process.  I've ran into each case once on XP systems:   An Apple installer that insisted my admin accounts weren't and refused to uninstall, and a fiasco involving a user trying to install Symantec Corporate AV on top of Norton Home resulting in two crashing uninstallers and no internet.

Comment: @DanNeely So on the very odd occasion you actually do use 3rd party uninstallers and with success (when the inbuilt uninstaller utility has failed) ?

Comment: @Simon actually I didn't, at the time I don't think I was aware of any free tools to do it.  The QT issue I ignored since I was planning on a new system in the near future; and it wasn't annoying enough to risk breaking anything.  The Norton/Symantec one I did the hard way:  3 hours manually scrubbing the registry and another 30 minutes doing the same on the file system.  In that case the lack of internet access without a 4 hour round trip drive forced my hand; had I realized how much work was involved I probably would've used the recovery disk to do a clean OS install.

Comment: @DanNeely Thats definitely doing it the hard way, i'm guessing you wouldn't recommend doing those things today ?

Comment: @Simon no, I wouldn't.  That problem turned out to be a lot more of a mess than I suspected from attempted phone diagnosis; and since it happened a decade ago the laptop didn't have wifi built in so I couldn't hunt for a coffee shop to look for an automated cleanup tool and I badly underestimated how hard it was going to be. (Without Symantec Corporate installed and working Novel refused it access to the schools wired network.)