# Can you install windows software from bootable OS

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot

I really think this question might be odd but I will ask anyway it should clear some other concepts to me.

if you have a Windows install in hard disk and you have any Linux distro that can read NTFS file system install on bootable usb.

When you boot from the usb you can actually mount the Windows hard disk to Linux and scan whatever you like if not encrypted, I wonder if there way to install Windows softwares 'setup.exe' using Linux to the Windows hard disk?

or disassemble 'setup.exe' and do manually what the installer will do?

Comment: WinRE doesn't have the required services to install programs.  Linux doesn't have the required services either for obvious reasons.

Comment: This is a similar Q: https://superuser.com/questions/682851/is-it-possible-to-install-software-on-windows-from-a-linux-live-usb?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't install Windows software in a Windows partition from a different OS. Installing software often entails more than just copying files.

However, very simple software intended to run from its own folder and not requiring additions to or changes in the Windows Registry can be extracted to the said partition from other OS in dual boot or from a live session.

Any `setup.exe` installer is likely to be the former case.

Comment: You cleared some concepts thank you, what about installing Windows as persistent partition on USB (if this a thing), boot from it, installing what i want on the Original Windows partition do you think this will work?

Answer (score -1):

If what you're asking is whether you can run Windows applications on Linux, try [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). Some things don't work perfectly, but it is the closest you will get. Welcome to superuser, by the way!

Comment: I'm glad to be part of this community, thanks you for Wine suggestion but i'm looking in to installing Windows software on Windows using other OS.